# Rewrite this to not contain subquery so I can add to view

Tags: mysql

Please forgive my ignorance - I'm learning as I go with MySQL and I'm really stuck on this one:

I've just got this query working, but when I try to add it to the view I need it to run in I can't because of the subquery.  I can't work out how to avoid the subquery - can any of you more knowledgeable people point me in the right direction please?

```
(SELECT `clients`.`Name` AS `ClientName`, `computers`.`Name` AS `ComputerName`, BackupName, results.Source, results.Result, results.Message, results.TimeGen, results.EventID
FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
  eventlogs.`ComputerID`, (
    CASE
      WHEN `eventlogs`.message LIKE '% job %'     
    THEN SUBSTR(`eventlogs`.`Message`, (LOCATE(' job ', `eventlogs`.`Message`) + 6), ((LOCATE('finished', `eventlogs`.`Message`) - LOCATE(' job ', `eventlogs`.`Message`)) - 8)) 
      ELSE NULL 
    END
  ) AS `BackupName`, `eventlogs`.`Source` AS `Source`, (
    CASE
      WHEN `eventlogs`.`message` LIKE 'Endpoint%Backup job % finished with Success%'
    THEN 'Pass' 
      WHEN `eventlogs`.`message` LIKE 'Endpoint%Backup job % finished with Warning%'
    THEN 'Pass-Warn' 
      WHEN `eventlogs`.`message` LIKE 'Endpoint%Backup job % finished with Fail%'      
    THEN 'FAIL' 
      WHEN `eventlogs`.`message` LIKE 'Endpoint%Backup job % finished with Error%'
    THEN 'FAIL' 
      ELSE 'Unknown - ASK ALEX!' 
    END
  ) AS `Result`, `eventlogs`.`Message` AS `Message`, `eventlogs`.`TimeGen` AS `TimeGen`, `eventlogs`.`EventID` AS `EventID` 

  FROM `eventlogs` 

  WHERE (
    `eventlogs`.`TimeGen` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
    AND eventlogs.source = "Veeam Endpoint Backup" 
    AND EventID < 10000
    AND EventID != 110
    AND EventID != 1
  )
) AS results
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT eventlogs.`ComputerID`,
  (CASE
  WHEN `eventlogs`.message LIKE '% job %'     
THEN SUBSTR(`eventlogs`.`Message`, (LOCATE(' job ', `eventlogs`.`Message`) + 6), ((LOCATE('finished', `eventlogs`.`Message`) - LOCATE(' job ', `eventlogs`.`Message`)) - 8)) 
  ELSE NULL 
END) AS `BackupName`, `eventlogs`.`Source` AS `Source`, eventlogs.Message, MAX(TimeGen) AS TimeGen, EventID
 FROM   `eventlogs` 

WHERE (
`eventlogs`.`TimeGen` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
AND eventlogs.source = "Veeam Endpoint Backup" 
AND EventID < 10000
AND EventID != 110
AND EventID != 1 )
 GROUP BY ComputerID, Source, BackupName) AS latest USING (ComputerID, Source, BackupName, TimeGen)
JOIN `computers` USING (ComputerID)
JOIN `clients` USING (ClientID)
)
```

Basically for each (computer + BackupName ) I need the most recent event, on which I then make a judgement and output the Result. Unfortunately the BackupName is parsed from text in the eventlogs.Message column.

Sorry it's rather long.  Any help or suggestions most welcome - thanks!

Comment: You understand the problem . . . MySQL has silly restrictions on the queries in views.  If you want help, I would suggest starting with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Realised I could completely rewrite and just apply jusgements to data from the "latest" dataset without all the complexity.  Just hope that this actually does what I want in practice LOL.  Thanks Gordon.

```
SELECT `clients`.`Name` AS `ClientName`, `computers`.`Name` AS `ComputerName`, (CASE
  WHEN `eventlogs`.message LIKE '% job %'     
THEN SUBSTR(`eventlogs`.`Message`, (LOCATE(' job ', `eventlogs`.`Message`) + 6), ((LOCATE('finished', `eventlogs`.`Message`) - LOCATE(' job ', `eventlogs`.`Message`)) - 8)) 
  ELSE NULL 
END) AS `BackupName`, `eventlogs`.`Source` AS `Source`, (
    CASE
      WHEN `eventlogs`.`message` LIKE 'Endpoint%Backup job % finished with Success%'
    THEN 'Pass' 
      WHEN `eventlogs`.`message` LIKE 'Endpoint%Backup job % finished with Warning%'
    THEN 'Pass-Warn' 
      WHEN `eventlogs`.`message` LIKE 'Endpoint%Backup job % finished with Fail%'      
    THEN 'FAIL' 
      WHEN `eventlogs`.`message` LIKE 'Endpoint%Backup job % finished with Error%'
    THEN 'FAIL' 
      ELSE 'Unknown - ASK ALEX!' 
    END
  ) AS `Result`, eventlogs.Message, MAX(TimeGen) AS TimeGen, EventID
FROM    `eventlogs`  JOIN `computers` USING (ComputerID)
JOIN `clients` USING (ClientID)
WHERE (
`eventlogs`.`TimeGen` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
AND eventlogs.source = "Veeam Endpoint Backup" 
AND EventID < 10000
AND EventID != 110
AND EventID != 1 )
GROUP BY ComputerID, Source, BackupName
```